# Replace all inconsistent character from a String in Java

Tags: java

Well, i have a string with letters, digits and some "strange" character. I wanna replace this "strange" character with a "white space".

Look my original string:

```
AVE  14 DE JULHO N�130
```

I wanna replace to:

```
AVE 14 DE JULHO N 130
```

This is just a example, but i have a big file with a lot of "normal character" and another "strange characters"

Comment: `string.replace("[^0-9A-Za-z]", " ");`

Comment: Use Regular Expressions, et Patterns

Comment: @Cruncher string.replace("[^\w]", " ")

Comment: How about reading the file with the correct character encoding, so that N�130 is actually read as Nº130? Wouldn't that be better?

Comment: The problem is a have a lot of character different of letter and digit should be accepted, like: ':','/','+','-','.',' ','....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is a have a lot of character different of letter and digit
>   should be accepted, like: ':','/','+','-','.',' ','

Added more characters to the group. If you want a character to be allowed you literally just type it into the square brackets.

```
string.replaceAll("[^0-9A-Za-z\\s:,/+\\-.]", " ");
```

`^` is the complement operator. This will replace all non-digits and non-letters with a white space. If you ever need to add more characters to not erase, just add characters in the group.

Comment: `.` no but `-` should be escaped.

Comment: Poor characters that are not in your class like `!` `@` `#` `$` `%` `^` and so on... None of them will survive your replacement. Hope OP is not using them.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `replaceAll` to replace all characters that match a pattern:

```
String bad = "AVE  14 DE JULHO N�130";
String badPattern = "[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]"; // anything not a good character
String good = bad.replaceAll(badPattern, " ");
```

Or, if you know the range of bad characters:

```
String bad = "AVE  14 DE JULHO N�130";
String badPattern = "[\\u0080-\\uffff]"; // anything above U+007f
String good = bad.replaceAll(badPattern, " ");
```

Note that the last is just an example of a positive match pattern, not a recommendation of what range to use! That range in particular would eliminate most accent marks.

**EDIT** It's most likely that those "strange" characters are actually good characters that were interpreted using the wrong character encoding somewhere in the process that built (or used) the string. It might be better to find and correct the places where there are encoding errors rather than trying to filter out the results of the errors.

Comment: +1 for part in edit. It is better to fix cause of problem than effects.

Answer (score 0):

The most easiest regex pattern is  `\W` with `replaceAll`. Just use:

```
 string.replaceAll("\\W", " ");
```

**Example:**

```
    String original= "AVE  14 DE JULHO N�130";
    String after=original.replaceAll("\\W", " ");
    System.out.println(after);
```

**Output:** AVE  14 DE JULHO N 130

Comment: The problem with this is that it will replace most punctuation with spaces. See OP's comment to the original question.